# android sqlite database import does not change

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want to modify the android application data base.

I export and modify and import again.

But the data import does not change.

I use the sqlitestudio tool.

What is the problem? Any idea?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please explain, or you'll soon be receiving a bunch of down votes.

Comment: What android application database are u talking about?

Answer (score 0):

i think you import sqllite database into your project which already created right?

todo so do following thing

goto --> DDMS --> open file explorer -->select data dir-->anorher time select data--> your package name-->database dir--> your dbfile pull it from the device then remove it

now click button push file into device select database dir and open the file from its location make sure that file is in database dir. thats done you successfully imported the  db.
thx...